# Styled Component only applying style to nested selector

Tags: reactjs, sass, styled-components

I want all of my text to be weight 800, including a span with the className of txt-rotate. Additionally, the child span will be colored and underlined. To do this, I am using this styled component definition:

```
export const Slider = styled.h2`
  font-weight: 800;
  .txt-rotate {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.primaryColor};
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
`;
```

And then this is when I use the component:

```
<Slider>I'm a&nbsp;
    <span className="txt-rotate" 
          data-period={2000} 
          data-rotate='[ "Hacker.", "Coder.", "Maker.", "Entrepreneur." ]' />
</Slider>
```

The span's text ends up being the `primaryColor` and the text is underlined, but none of the text is weighted. In the inspector, I see that there is no style being applied to the Slider's div except for the span within it.

Update:
I fixed my problem by reordering the exports of my styled components. The styled component `Slider` was at the bottom, and now it works as the second to last styled component definition. Why would this be?

Answer (score 1):

> In order to see any effect using values other than 400 or 700, the font being used must have built-in faces that match those specified weights.

Please refer to https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/

```js
const Slider = window.styled.h2`
  font-weight: ${props => props.weight};
  background: ${props => props.background};
  .txt-rotate {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
`;
const App = () => (
 <div>
  <Slider weight="100" background="grey">
    One <span className="txt-rotate">I am a span (100)</span>
  </Slider>
  <Slider weight="200" background="green">
    Two <span className="txt-rotate">I am a span (200)</span>
  </Slider>
  <Slider weight="300" background="cyan">
    Three <span className="txt-rotate">I am a span (300)</span>
  </Slider>
  <Slider weight="400">
    Four <span className="txt-rotate">I am a span (400)</span>
  </Slider>
  <Slider weight="500">
    Five <span className="txt-rotate">I am a span (500)</span>
  </Slider>
  <Slider weight="600">
    Six <span className="txt-rotate">I am a span (600)</span>
  </Slider>
  <Slider weight="700">
    Seven <span className="txt-rotate">I am a span (700)</span>
  </Slider>
  <Slider weight="800">
    Eight <span className="txt-rotate">I am a span (800)</span>
  </Slider>
  <Slider weight="900">
    Nine <span className="txt-rotate">I am a span (900)</span>
  </Slider>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/4.4.1/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: The weight property works if I use a CSS file and apply styling that way or by applying via Chrome inspection tools. Also, any other styling outside of the .txt-rotate selector doesn't work including font-size.

Comment: Not sure what is exactly wrong with your project setup but I tried a snippet similar to your use case in the question. It seems to work fine.

Comment: I fixed my problem by reordering the exports of my styled components. The styled component `Slider` was at the bottom, and now it works at the second to bottom. Why would this be?